# Get all pending AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, request

How I can check all pending AJAX requests and skip all pending requests except last?
For example, I have 3 payment methods and when I click rapidly 3-5 times I see 1 pending request and 3-5 waiting requests. So I need skip all of them except the last one.

Comment: Would you not want to restrict them from doing that in the first place?

Comment: I'd suggest you disable that button until *the first* operation is done. Globally modifying AJAX operations isn't a good idea.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer, it's not a button. It's checkbox for payment and checkbox for shipping

Comment: If your doing your ajax logic in a binding using on() consider changing it to one().  This will cause the logic to only fire once.  If you need it to fire again later, you'd simply rebind when it becomes valid again.

Comment: disable checkbox until ajax completes

Comment: Anyone can modify/remove the `disabled` attribute if he/she nows how to `inspect elements` so it is better to use `on` events than the inline `onclick`. It makes the user hard to find the `callback`

Answer (score 4):

Use this type of pattern

```
// Is an ajax request pending?
var isPending = false;

function doAjax(){
    // If a request is pending, don't make another one
    if(isPending) return;
    // Set pending flag to true
    isPending = true;
    $.ajax({
        // parameters and stuff
    }).done(function(){
        // reset the pending flag
        isPending = false;
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can cancel the ajax calls by using timeout for each call 
http://geekswithblogs.net/lorint/archive/2006/03/07/71625.aspx

Comment: Don't provide ***link only*** answers without some relevant code. Links rot and a dead link makes this answer completely useless in the future. This should really only be a comment